# firebase ui phone auth activity leaking

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui, leakcanary

After launching the phone authendication via firebase-ui i get the next leak report from leakcanary. I dont think i am doing anything wrong.

i also get leak from ConstraintLayout and SubmitConfirmation
CodeFragment

````
LibraryLeak(className=com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.PhoneActivity, leakTrace=
┬
├─ android.view.ViewGroup$ViewLocationHolder
│    Leaking: NO (a class is never leaking)
│    GC Root: System class
│    ↓ static ViewGroup$ViewLocationHolder.sPool
│                                          ~~~~~
├─ android.util.Pools$SynchronizedPool
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ Pools$SynchronizedPool.mPool
│                             ~~~~~
├─ java.lang.Object[]
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ array Object[].[0]
│                     ~~~
├─ android.view.ViewGroup$ViewLocationHolder
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ ViewGroup$ViewLocationHolder.mRoot
│                                   ~~~~~
├─ androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
│    Leaking: YES (View.mContext references a destroyed activity)
│    mContext instance of com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.PhoneActivity with mDestroyed = true
│    View#mParent is set
│    View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    ↓ ConstraintLayout.mContext
╰→ com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.PhoneActivity
​     Leaking: YES (ConstraintLayout↑ is leaking and Activity#mDestroyed is true and ObjectWatcher was watching this)
​     key = 5a91cbea-396c-44e5-9516-f9a5442198f8
​     watchDurationMillis = 5770
​     retainedDurationMillis = 768
, retainedHeapByteSize=645359, pattern=instance field android.view.ViewGroup$ViewLocationHolder#mRoot, description=In Android P, ViewLocationHolder has an mRoot field that is not cleared in its clear() method. Introduced in https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/86b326012813f09d8f1de7d6d26c986a909d Bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112792715)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a LibraryLeak, which means it's a known leak in a library or the Android framework code. At the bottom you can see the pattern:

> pattern: instance field android.view.ViewGroup$ViewLocationHolder#mRoot,
>
> description: In Android P, ViewLocationHolder has an mRoot field that
> is not cleared in its clear() method. Introduced in
> https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/86b326012813f09d8f1de7d6d26c986a909d
> Bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112792715